# id is going undefined when i try to update something in codeigniter its taking only id 1

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

```
$('#showdata').on('click', '.item-edit', function(){

            var id = $(this).attr('data');
            $('#update_model').modal('show');
         //s  $('#myform').attr('action', '<?php echo site_url() ?>/Admin/Authorisation/update');
      $.ajax({
             type: 'ajax',
             method: 'get',
             url: '<?php echo site_url() ?>/Admin/Authorisation/edit',
             data: {id: client_id},
             async: false,
            // dataType: 'json',
             success: function(data)
             {

                 alert(id);
                 $('input[name=fname]').val(data.client_fname);
                 $('input[name=lname]').val(data.client_lname);
                 $('input[name=email]').val(data.client_email);
                 $('input[name=phone]').val(data.client_phone);
                 $('input[name=country]').val(data.client_country_id);
                 $('input[name=client_id]').val(data.id);

             }, 

             error: function()
                {
                    alert('could not Edit');
                }

         });    
        });  
            function get_data(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'ajax',
                url: '<?php echo site_url() ?>/Admin/Authorisation/get_data',
                async: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    var html = '';
                    var i;
                    for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                        html +='<tr>'+
                                    '<td>'+data[i].client_id+'</td>'+
                                    '<td>'+data[i].client_fname+'</td>'+
                                    '<td>'+data[i].client_lname+'</td>'+
                                    '<td>'+data[i].client_email+'</td>'+
                                    '<td>'+data[i].client_phone+'</td>'+
                                     '<td>'+data[i].client_country_id+'</td>'+
                                     '<td>' +data[i].password+'</td>'+
                                     '<td>'+data[i].status+'</td>'+
                                    '<td>'+
                                        '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-info item-edit" data="'+data[i].client_id+'">update</a>'+
                                        '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-danger item-delete" data="'+data[i].client_id+'">Delete</a>'+
                                    '</td>'+
                                '</tr>';
                    }
                    $('#showdata').html(html);
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert('Could not get Data from Database');
                }
            });
        }
        });


    </script>
```

id is going undefined  when i try to update something in codeigniter its taking only id 1. Not gething the correct id. when i alert my id its saying undefined. and in place of id its going null so could not update any thing

Comment: Show your `html` code where you defined `var id = $(this).attr('data');`

Comment: you should use `id = 'item-edit-'+data[i].client_id)` with record id instead of `.item-edit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is you are getting your id in variable named id, but you are passing it as client_id.

```
     data: {id: client_id},
```

this should be `data: {id: id},`